# 1993 Ford Taurus 3.8

Tags: ford, oil, taurus

I have a 93 Ford Taurus. There is a lot of oil in the radiator, but no water in the oil. The oil was close to 3 quarts low. I've never seen where there was oil in the water, but no water in the oil. Could it be a blown head gasket? When we purchased the car a while back it had a blown head gasket. We took the heads off, had them shaved, then replace the gaskets.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The 93 Ford 3.8 engine utilizes [Torque-to-Yield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque-to-yield_fastener) head bolts. If you didn't replace the head bolts and torque/turn them correctly, you've most likely caused the same problem over you were trying to fix. Plus, if you don't do the sequence properly, you'll have issues again. Here is the installation process for the heads:

> 1. Clean the cylinder head bolt hole threads with a tap. Lightly oil all bolt and stud bolt threads before installation except those entering coolant jackets.
> 2. Position new head gasket(s) on the cylinder block using the dowels for alignment.
> 3. Position the cylinder head(s) on the block and install the new bolts hand tight.
> 4. Torque the head bolts in the proper sequence as follows:
>
>    - 37 ft. lbs. (50 Nm)
>    - 45 ft. lbs. (60 Nm)
>    - 52 ft. lbs. (70 Nm)
>    - 59 ft. lbs. (80 Nm)
>    - Loosen each bolt one at a time in sequence 2-3 turns, then torque to 11-18 ft. lbs. (15-25 Nm)
>    - Rotate each bolt in sequence an additional 90 degrees.

Here is an image of what the torque sequence looks like on the head:

[image: Copied from Chilton's Auto Repair Manual]

(**Source:** Chilton Auto Repair Manual 1993-1997 Pg 13-34)